# Separators in data file for azure ml studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have csv file news.csv with such data:

```
ID \t TITLE \t URL \t PUBLISHER \t CATEGORY \t STORY \t HOSTNAME \t TIMESTAMP
```

But Azure ML studio experiments dont see Separators \t and when I try to select column I cant do it. How to fix it?

Comment: What does your experiment currently look like?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your file extension to .tsv. As AML doesn't allow choosing custom delimiters while uploading your file, it looks at your file extension. Changing the file extension will solve the issue.